# Profile view counter - variable showing as null despite being declared and used elsewhere

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, counter

I'm trying to build a profile view counter with PHP and jquery ajax. I want the page count to be fetched, and incremented and input into the database when the page is loaded.

Here is my jquery:

```
 var views = "<?php echo $views;?>";
 $(document).ready(function(){

    view = parseInt(views) + 1;
    $.ajax({
            url: "user.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              'views' : view //array of objects
            },
            success:function(data, response){  
            console.log(data);    
            alert(view);

               }
        });
```

and the php that picks up the ajax:

```
if(isset($_GET["id"]) && isset($_GET['activ'])){
    $activ = preg_replace('#[^0-2]#i', '', $_GET['activ']);
    $id = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']);
} else {
    header("location: http://www.unlimitedtutors.com");
    exit(); 
}

if (isset($_POST['views'])){
      $views = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['views']);
      $views = intval($views);
      $sql1 = "UPDATE users SET views='$views' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
      $query1 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql1);
        echo $id;
}
```

the problem is that the $id variable doesnt seem to be showing up although I know it's been declared. This obviously means that the sql is not working correctly. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you setting `id` and `activ` in your call to the PHP? It looks like you're just calling `user.php`, rather than `user.php?id=xx&activ=yy`, since you're looking for them in $_GET.

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` on `$id` to see if it's what you expect it to be, and isn't breaking your query.

Comment: aaahhhh - i see - need to include the additional get variables when calling a function inside an isset requiring those to be set! Duh! - mega facepalm! thanks @andrewsi

Comment: @Mobaz - since you're POSTing, you can just add the variables to `data`, and change the PHP so that it's looking for the in $_POST. It'll keep things a little more consistent.

Comment: why are you using javascript/ajax to do this? in `user.php` can't you just get the current viewcount from the db, increment it by one, then do the sql update? the way your code is currently written, a user could pass whatever value they want (say, 999999 views). also, `'views' : view` is not an array of objects, it's a number.

Comment: @sgroves - thanks - i asked myself that question and then just used php anyway - another facepalm